# Storing uploaded images for website

Tags: php, web-development, database, json, file-systems

I'm developing a website (using PHP, JS, and MYSQL) which allow user to upload images. My requirements are as below:

1. User is able to upload 1 or multiple images at a time.
2. Website is able to save the original images and using the original images to create a re-sized version e.g. 500x500 px

### What I've done

I need some opinions regarding the decisions I've took/implemented as below, let me know if it is right or wrong :)

1. I did not store the images in database as blobs.
2. I have an image table in the database which store image name and image path. The image path is a string which will be the exact folder name in the filesystem, the image name is the name of the image uploaded by user. Combine both will create a path direct to the file system.
3. Using above method I am able to query the images as if it was stored in my database but actually I am just mapping them.
4. Is my approach correct? I am thinking about JSON but is it useful in this case?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105191/store-images-in-the-database-or-in-files-with-a-database-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did not store the images in database as blobs.

Ok

> I have an image table in the database which store image name and image path. The image path is a string which will be the exact folder name in the filesystem, the image name is the name of the image uploaded by user.

So if 2 users upload a mommy.png you will have a conflict isn't it ?

Usually in order to not have any conflict and to not have huge performance loss when having a huge amount of image in the same folder (it depends on the type of filesystem) you create intermediary folder which name correspond to some hash.

Exemple : I have a system which compute a MD5 on my file which is like '123456789ab...' it will be stored under 12/34/56/123456789ab'.

In order to retrieve the fill i have a dedicated url which look like http://.../image/1.

Note  using database id expose your website to be easy to harvest consider either :

- generating a uuid for each of your image and use it as identifier if you all the image are public
- check access right to the image depending on who is connected.

> Is my approach correct? I am thinking about JSON but is it useful in this case?

Nop JSON isn't made to transfer files.

If the approach i suggested is a bit complicated consider at least the following : create one directory at least per user and store their image in. If the images aren't public, don't map `http://.../image/<user>/<image>` so easily. Map it to some code where you can perform right check (is user == currentUser ? , is user in friendlist of the image's owner ?,...)

Comment: First of all thank you for your valuable feedback. Actually.... for each user registered, I created a folder in my filesystem XD (but inside the folder is blank). After that, when they upload any images, I will capture the time in the format YYYYMMDDHHMISS e.g. 20160812170710 and make a folder with this name. This name will also stored in my database  as image path. Therefore I am able to map the image path (in db) and the filesystem path~

Comment: hum so if the user upload multiple image at the same time, they may be created in the same second right ?  You should add milliseconds :p

Comment: Technically you are right! I would like to share why I did this, for example.. Within 1 seconds user uploaded 4 images, program will capture and insert data into db 1 by 1.. therefore, I am able to know at that particular seconds, in which sequence the images being uploaded and created. This is why I stop at seconds instead of milliseconds as the folder name...

Comment: I don't get it, if you add the millisecond like `YYYYMMDDHHMISSssss` you will still be able to know that ? And if the database and filesystem are fast enough to have two image of one user created user's folder the same second, the second file will overwrite the first one on the hard drive. Unless the YYYYMMDDHHMISS is not the whole file name and is just a suffix ?

Comment: @4LeaveCover Or just name the images by their Id in the database..

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Alternatex is right, the better approach is probably to use unique IDs as file names for the images, which avoids collisions totally. Store the original name instead in the database table (together with any other metadata you might need, for example name of uploader, time of uploading, description provided). That way, you do not have to deal with problematic file names your file system might not support, or similar quirks. Using different folders (maybe per day or hour) is still a good idea, to avoid file system restrictions concerning no of files per folder.

Comment: @DocBrown To use unique IDs as file names, meaning I need to rename the images in filesystem after knowing the IDs retrieve from my DB is that correct? Other than that, I believe collisions can happen if user for example select image1.jpg in folder A then select another image1.jpg in folder B and uploaded both to my server :D later they can say my system sucks which may cause file overwrite hahaha

Comment: @4LeaveCover: I don't know how you implemented your uploading mechanism, but does it require the name of the uploaded file to be identical with its original name? Can't you directly specify a new name?